# Why function can return array of chars, but can't return array of other types?

Tags: c++

```
const char* myf()
 {
  return "string";
 }
```

but it'sn't work with arrays. Its looks as special ugly language design limitation.

Comment: `const char*` **is not** an array of chars. It is a pointer to a char. (i.e. the address of the char in memory.)

Comment: This function does not return an array.

Comment: yesm i forgot about this, but why it not work with other type?

Comment: you could also return a pointer to the first element in a custom type array, but how would you know where the array ends? (strings can be null-terminated because the null character has special meaning, but that wont work for custom types)

Comment: ... btw just dont do it but use `std::vector`

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you want to work but doesn't?

Comment: I just want to understand key ideas of the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Litteral strings are special animals in C++. They behave as is they were pointers to static const arrays. As you function is declared to return a `const char *` you get a perfectly defined behaviour.

But the same can be done with any other array, *provided it is static*:

```
const int * myintfunc() {
    static const int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3};
    return arr;
}
```

Will have the same defined behaviour and will return on each call a pointer to the (first element of the) same array containing the integers 1, 2 and 3.

If it was not const, the behaviour would be perfectly defined too, and each call would return a pointer to the first element of the same array. Simply the content of the array could be modified.

If the array had automatic storage, the function would still return a pointer to its first element, but the array would be destroyed when the function returns and the returned pointer would be a *dangling* one (pointing to an object that has reached its end of life), and using it is Undefined Behaviour.